# How to implement WebUI object in JUnit

Tags: junit, katalon-studio, webui

I'm working with Katalon. Now I want to convert the test cases into JUnit. But the problem is,  the package of WebUI is not supported with JUnit.

How to do this? Is this possible?

Comment: See https://forum.katalon.com/t/junit4-katalon-studio-integration-by-a-built-in-keyword/17637.

Comment: Cucumber BDD is also supported and it is running on JUnit.